# Count variable within returned aggregate results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am performing an aggregate and am looking at how to perform within the original aggregate method the ability to breakdown the `SUM` total further. I currently return total events within a distance, grouped by cluster code. I would like to have the total count broken down with each category.

I know I can perform a `$group` query as so

```
var events = Events.aggregate(
       [
          {
            $match : {
                "location.loc" : {
                   $geoWithin : {
                     $centerSphere : [[long,lat], milesToRadian(radius) ]
                   }
                 }
            }
          },
          {
            $group : {
               _id : { 'cluster_code' : "$location.cluster_code"},
               count : { $sum : 1 }
            }
          }
       ]
    )
```

I'm aware I can add a extra parameter `{"category" : "$category"}` within my `$group` query to break this down for each category. I can then perform a grouping method to create the right format I am looking for. This feels like I can improve the query.

What I am trying to achieve is having a SUM count then a count for each `category`. Similar to this:

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "cluster_code": "FK",
    },
    "Run" : 2,
    "Swim" : 1
    "count": 3
  },
```

Is this possible in a single aggregate query?

**UPDATE**

Sample dummy document

```
{
_id : "df",
"location" : {
   //...
},
"category" : "Run"
}
```

Comment: what your sample doc looks like?

Comment: Updated above. `category` is a top level string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation pipeline in `3.4.4` version.

`$group` by `cluster_code` and `category` to get the count for each grouping.

`$zip` each `category` key value pair separately followed by `$arrayToObject` to create output format structure.

Use `$addFields` to push the `cluster_code` & `total` into `data`.

Use `$replaceRoot` to promote the `data` embedded document to top level.

```
aggregate(
{$group : {
       _id : { "cluster_code" : "$location.cluster_code", category:"$category"},
       count : { $sum : 1 }
    }
},
{$group : {
      _id : "$_id.cluster_code",
      categorycount : { $push:{category:"$_id.category", count:"$count" }},
      total:{$sum:"$count"}
    }
},
{$addFields:{data: {$arrayToObject:{$zip:{inputs:["$categorycount.category", "$categorycount.count"]}}}}},
{$addFields:{"data.cluster_code": "$_id", "data.total":"$total"}},
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$data"}}
)
```

Comment: 2 groups did the job and makes sense